# Rotate all video in a folder with ffmpeg?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, script, gnome-terminal

I have a lot of videos which are recorder 90 • rotated so I want to rotate all videos 90 degrees clockwise direction. If this possible?

**I used for loop but there is some mistake because of spaces character in their names and ordering is not correct with my script. It prompts me to overwrite.**. Do you know what I need type?. Also my command is this `ffmpeg -i input(filename).mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 input(filename)%02d.mp4` to make this fastly. It just add flag to rotate and my video player can understand the flag.

EDIT:

```
for i in /home/makgun/Desktop/Run*/*.mp4; do ffmpeg -i $i -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 $i%02d.mp4; done
```

I used this command for **/home/makgun/Desktop/Running\ Man/*.mp4** but it doesnt work unless I delete the space charecter from **Running Man** folder. And Also I want to add suffix like **$i01, $i02 ..**

EDIT 2:
I want to be named all output as `OrginalFileName01.mp4, OrginalFileName02.mp4, etc.` 
Also if possible to delete file when convention is successfully finished. Because it decreases free space (a huge amount) on my hdd.

Comment: Please provide the `for` loop you used. It can probably be repaired with some quoting.

Comment: How exactly would that suffix of yours work? Please provide an example of how a file would be renamed, without code or variables.

Comment: @DanielB please read my edit.

Comment: I’m still unsure about the exact nature of your numbering scheme. `a.mp4` be “converted” to `a01.mp4` and a second file `b.mp4` would result in `b02.mp4`? Isn’t it just enough to make it something like `a_rotated.mp4`?

Comment: Yes you are correct and this is my point. If it is possible make it like `a01.mp4` , `b02.mp4` ,it will be more useful for me but it is hard to write than i think `a_rotated.mp4 , b_rotated.mp4` is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that could be easy with "find":

```
export SRCDIR="/home/makgun/Desktop/Running Man"
export DSTDIR="foobar"
if [ -d "DSTDIR" ] || mkdir -p "$DSTDIR"
find "$SRCDIR" -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffmpeg -i '{}' -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 copy_{} \;
```

Comment: can you explain this command? Like `mkdir -p "$DSTDIR" ` also ` ffmpeg -i '{}'`

Comment: I used this code with some modifications. But there is still `output filename error` like `copy_home/makgun/Desktop/Running Man/filename.mp4: No such file or directory` . How to add variables to be named for output files with their original name and add suffix like `FileName01.mp4`

Comment: - `mkdir -p "$DSTDIR"` is to create the destination folder with their parents.

Comment: `ffmepeg -i '{}'`: the `{}` is used by find to replace in line the path of the found file

Comment: Ive learnt what they means but now I have to add variable for output fileName. Do you have any opinion about that?  I add this line ` FILES=`ls /home/makgun/Desktop/Running\ Man/*.mp4 ` After that I changed output like ` $FILES ` instead of `copy_{}`

Comment: I do not understand you makgun... {} is automatically replaced by `find` without any variable, if `find` gets an file, the file path is replaced where you put `{}` after the `-exec` option

Comment: when I typed output name of rotated video as `copy_{}` but then ffmpeg gives me error for `output directory` like `copy_/home/makgun/Desktop/filename.mp4 :No such file or directory `

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `{}` is replaced by full path and not by file name. Try it again but doing a cd into `$SRCDIR` before

Comment: It gives me same error